# MySQL - Insert Trigger to Take the Value of a Column in One Table and Put it Into Another

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have two tables: `orderLine` and `product`. I'm trying to make a trigger that takes the `salePrice` from the product table and then puts it into the orderLine table (based on the UPC?) when a new orderLine is inserted.

```
orderLine
----------
orderID 
upc 
productName 
quantity 
price


product
----------
upc 
plu 
productName 
description 
unitPrice 
salePrice 
departmentID
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Do you _need_ a `TRIGGER`?  Or would it be better to do the `INSERT` yourself?